# Cannot access request in pandas library

Tags: pandas

```
import panda as pd

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f542dbfa5144> in <module>
```

----> 1 import panda as pd

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panda__init__.py in 
----> 1 from request import PandaRequest
      2 from models import Video, Cloud, Encoding, Profile, Notifications, PandaDict
      3 from models import GroupRetriever, SingleRetriever
      4 from models import PandaError
      5 from upload_session import UploadSession

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your import statement is wrong 
please try

import pandas as pd